# Typescript type annotations with varible

Tags: javascript, string, typescript

I have a variable and I want to set the variable as typescript type annotations.

```
type mytype = "image1" | "image2" | "image3"

images: mytype;
```

That is no problem, but I want to generate the mytype from an Array. How is that possible?

```
images = ["image1", "image2", "image3"]
mytype = images.map(i => '"' + i + '"').join(' | ')
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you think like this?

```
const images = ["image1", "image2", "image3"] as const;
type mytype = typeof images[number]; // mytype is now "image1" | "image2" | "image3"
```

Comment: Is it possible to put an existing array to the constant?

Comment: @DanWiedenhoever You can define the type only from constant array, otherwise the type would be for nothing, because it wouldn't know which value it holds.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options to tell Typescript you want to assign an array to a variable:

**1. Using the [] operator**

The easiest and best way is to use `[]` after your type

```
type mytype = "image1" | "image2" | "image3"

images: mytype[];
```

**2. Casting a type to an Array**

```
type mytype = "image1" | "image2" | "image3"

images: Array<mytype>;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use an enum for this case, unfortunately I don't think you can create the type on the fly based on dynamic values (or if you should, it defeats the purpose of ts).

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html

```
enum Images {
    ImageType1 = 'image1',
    ImageType2 = 'image2',
    ...
};
const values = Object.values(Images); // will be an array ['image1', 'image2', ...];

// use as a type
const foo = (image: Images) => {
   // do stuff, "image" will be restricted to 'image1' | 'image2' | ... values
}
```